# Can I use Peertalk or usbmuxd in a sandboxed macOS app?

Tags: ios, macos, usb, appstore-sandbox

[Peertalk](https://github.com/rsms/peertalk) is a library that provides communication between a mac and an iOS device via the lightning/USB cable. It establishes the connection by doing this:

```
  struct sockaddr_un addr;
  addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(addr.sun_path, "/var/run/usbmuxd");
  socklen_t socklen = sizeof(addr);
  if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, socklen) == -1) {
    if (error) *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:NSPOSIXErrorDomain code:errno userInfo:nil];
    return NO;
  }
```

This is fine in an non-sandboxed app.  In a sandboxed app, even with network and USB allowed it fails with the errno `EPERM` - Operation Not Permitted.

Is there any way to get this to work in a sandboxed Mac app?

---

UPDATE:

Adding a temporary exception to the `.entitlements` didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
    <string>/var/run/usbmuxd</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Isn't the path supposed to be "/private/var/run/usbmuxd" instead?

Comment: @superg It's the same thing - the /private filesystem contains links to the files on the root filesystem.

Comment: Hi there... did you get any answers about this? We are also trying to get PeerTalk to work on a sandbox MacOS app. Thanks for sharing! Cheers

Comment: I did it with a non-sandboxed relay app that the user could download and install outside of the app-store.

Comment: There is any way to submit or download in from app-store? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, it's not possible.

The solution I eventually came to was a relay app that the user could manually download and install as a non-sandbox app.  The main app communicated with the relay through the network loopback address, then the relay communicated with the device through usbmuxd.